# JSF session beans best practices

Tags: jsf, session-variables, backing-beans

I am working on a JSF application that was written overseas and it has some performance issues.

Ive been trying to understand why the application might run slow and ive noticed that every backing bean is session scoped, and many beans use other beans, so they are likely all instantiated.

There are maybe 40 backing beans each containing around 4000 lines of code and lots of moving parts.

Can someone confirm or deny my hunch that all this crap in each session is making the application sluggish?

Comment: Don't guess. Profile it.

Comment: i have. i see memory load increase as the user goes around on the site, and the number of loaded classes increase, almost never decrease. i think that putting EVERYTHING into your session accounts for this

Comment: You've just answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this may be the cause of performance issues. Session scoped beans are only created once for a session. So subsequent requests won't create new instances of these beans. But of cause making all beans session scoped is far away from good practice! :-)

Comment: Usually i try to put only stuff that is 'required' into the session, not everything that there can be. it seems to be that backing beans dont *need* to be session scoped unless there is a good reason

Comment: That is absolutely correct! It is good practice to do it that way as   you won't carry unnecessary state around in your session. But I don't think that putting everything into the session will cause performance issues. It is just not recommended because the app gets very "stateful" although it is not really required.